# LocationManager does not stop PendingIntent based requests when app is force stopped

Tags: android, gps, android-pendingintent, locationmanager, android-location

I've been dealing with locations on Android for a long time, but recently I've decided to focus more on PendingIntents for processing updates. From the docs, I tried to understand the edge cases, mainly, what would happen to my requests in case my app was terminated by either the system or force closed by the user. Unfortunately, the docs aren't very detailed about this, so I created a test app..

To my surprise, **if I request location updates using a PendingIntent and then terminate my app my request isn't cancelled**. This means that if I start a GPS request, and then decide to swipe away my app from the "recents" list, the GPS will keep trying to get a lock forever (or until the device is reboot) even though my app is no longer running. I've even tried Force Stopping the app which didn't help, and then manually stop the process which was still around in the list of cached processes but to my dismay not even that was able to stop the request!

I know that my app's process may still be restarted by the system when an update becomes available because my receivers are registered on a manifest level, but what surprises me is that I would expect the location manager to terminate my request given that **as far as I can tell I have no way whatsoever to clean after my app in these situations**.

What I mean by that is:

1. Imagine I just started a background single GPS request (I'm working on a background lib, so we're not tied to any activity or UI context) expecting to timeout it after 30 seconds if none was available.
2. The user decides to swipe my app away or force stop it at that time.
3. I get absolutely no guaranteed warning that I can hook up to, to clean my state and stop the GPS from trying to stay on forever. By that I mean that not even a service's onDestroy method is guaranteed to be called (it isn't really) in these situations.

I could always set a timeout beforehand on the alarm manager but that's just wrong, the request should stop with my app and not after a set period of time, wasting battery in the meantime for no good reason. Also, with GPS it really is hard to always specify a timeout beforehand, and with continuous update requests it becomes impossible. If I do get an update, I can then check if my app hasn't been killed in the meantime and stop the requests then..but what do I do if I never get an update like in a GPS while inside scenario?

Has anybody already found a proper/standard way to deal with this situations?

Tested on a Nexus 5 w/ 4.4.2

**Update:**

I'm still unable to work around this issue and have found that previous versions of Android (Galaxy Nexus 4.3) behave identically. If I request location updates using the PendingIntent method my requests do not stop if I force stop my app.

Comment: Swiping an app off the recent-tasks list is not "force-stopped" on most devices. That term is for pressing the Force Stop button for your app in Settings. For most devices, swiping the app out of the recent-tasks list will simply terminate your background process, if you had one. Everything else with the app (`AlarmManager` alarms, `PendingIntents` registered with `LocationManager`, etc.) should be left untouched.

Comment: Agreed but I had to keep the title short :) On the body I mention it only as an alternative to the actual "Force Stop" from the settings as the result I'm getting is the same. The point is that neither stops my location requests. For completeness sake, I've seen some reports that as of Kitkat, "swipe-offs" will also terminate running services (http://goo.gl/ad0nmj) but I'm yet to confirm it.

Comment: This could be a logic flaw. From the OS`s angle, there`s no reason to cancel a PendingIntent, cause receiver can be registered in AndroidManifest. So it has to believe everything`s fine, nothing`s crashing. I didn`t look deep into the source code, I suppose the manager should unregister non-handled PendingIntent.